# Rails "No route matches" when using param and no args to route helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

`config/routes.rb`:

```rb
resources :companies, param: :uid
```

Trying to use the route helper without any params results in an error as Rails finds `@company` and calls `id` on it getting `21520`, but that doesn't match the route key `company_uid`.

```rb
new_company_path 
# => ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"new", :company_id=>"21520"}, missing required keys: [:company_uid]
```

If I pass the values directly it works fine:

```rb
new_company_path(@company.uid) #=> "/companies/SP-3591/new"
new_company_path(@company_uid: company.uid) #=> "/companies/SP-3591/new"
```

Is there a way to tell Rails that the attribute is `uid`, so it calls that instead of `id`, making the call without params to `new_company_path` work?

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add `to_param` method in your model like this

```rb
class SomeModel
  def to_param
    uid
  end
end
```

Refer document [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Integration.html#method-i-to_param)
or you can try friendly_url gem